# Apache Beam Session Window doesn't return anything

Tags: python, apache-beam

Currently, I'm trying to calculate the total amount left in an e-commerce shopping cart. I have per occurrence the session id and the price of the product. Then I've created a Session Window with 15 seconds of lag, and finally, a CombinePerKey summing it all. However, after the window creation, there is no output being produced (using `beam.Map(print)` doesn't print anything). The code runs without any errors and I don't know what to do!

Here is an example of my data:

```
('2b88b00a-892a-4639-bce4-1ea17a7d6221', 2.54)
('324c685c-4281-48d5-8783-7a7416f7d2b3', 3.97)
('c99a50e8-2fac-4c4d-89ec-41c05f114554', 1.27)
('324c685c-4281-48d5-8783-7a7416f7d2b3', 4.29)
('c99a50e8-2fac-4c4d-89ec-41c05f114554', 1.27)
```

Here is my pipeline:

```
pipe = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

def encode_byte_string(element):
   print(element)
   element = str(element)
   return element.encode('utf-8')

ecommerce_data = (
        pipe
        | "Read from PubSub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
        | "Decode utf-8" >> beam.Map(lambda row: row.decode('utf-8'))
        | "Window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.Sessions(15))
        | "Combine per key - sum" >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
        | beam.Map(print)
        | "Encode to byte string" >> beam.Map(encode_byte_string)
        | "Write to output" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=output)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you shared the full code, it's because there isn't a key (or it is set incorrectly). Note that `row.decode('utf-8')` returns a type of string. To fix, convert the string into tuple as follows:

```py
ecommerce_data = (
        pipe
        | "Read from PubSub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
        | "Decode utf-8" >> beam.Map(lambda row: tuple(row.decode('utf-8')))
        | "Window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.Sessions(15))
        | "Combine per key - sum" >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
        | beam.Map(print)
        | "Encode to byte string" >> beam.Map(encode_byte_string)
        | "Write to output" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=output)
    )
```

(If you're receiving Pub/Sub data as encoded JSON, then you can add a key like this):

```py
        | "Decode utf-8" >> beam.Map(lambda row: json.loads(row.decode('utf-8')))
        | "Add key" >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row["id"], row["seconds"]))
        | "Window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.Sessions(15))
```